# Null Pointer Exception in RecyclerView within Fragment with Firestore

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to populate `recyclerView` with Java objects using Firestore. The RecyclerView is within a fragment. I am using a recyclerViewAdapter which extends the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` class. When I run the code, the app crashes immediately.

Here's the error.

```
.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

Here's some of the fragment Java code:

```
    public class EventsFragment extends Fragment{
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference eventRef = db.collection("Events");

    private EventRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.events_fragment, container, false);

        setUpRecyclerView();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView(){
        Query query = eventRef.limit(8);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Event> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Event>()
                .setQuery(query, Event.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new EventRecyclerAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

 }
```

Here's the fragment xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:title="Upcoming Events"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:id="@+id/events_recycler_view"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's the RecyclerAdapter code:

```
public class EventRecyclerAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Event, EventRecyclerAdapter.EventHolder> {

    public EventRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Event> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EventHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Event model) {
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EventHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.events_list_item,
                parent, false);
        return new EventHolder(v);
    }

    class EventHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;

        public EventHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the problem lies somewhere with the RecyclerView. I've been trying to find the problem for hours now. Is there something I'm overlooking? I just need it to run.

Comment: The full stack trace of the exception will tell you which line the error is on.  You should use that to find out which object is null.  It's the call to setLayoutManager - your recyclerview is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already noticed that `recyclerView` is `null` when you try to set the `LayoutManager` in `setUpRecyclerView()`

This happens because you are trying to "find" the `RecyclerView` in the `Activity`'s `View` tree before the `Fragment`'s `View` has actually been attached to it:

> RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view);

The first `Fragment` lifecycle method where you can put this statement is `onResume()` (at least in my example app on an emulator running Android 9)

But you can configure the `RecyclerView` much earlier because you can "find" it in the `Fragment`'s own `View` for example in `onViewCreated()`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    // etc.
}
```

Please note that the *view* parameter in `onViewCreated()` represents the `View` which you can get everywhere in the `Fragment` by calling `getView()`. But only after `onCreateView()` has finished, because the purpose of this method is creating and "publishing" the `Fragment`'s `View` in the first place.

Last not least, inside of `onCreateView()` you can "find" the `RecyclerView` by means of the newly inflated `View`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.events_fragment, container, false);

    //setUpRecyclerView();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext());
    // etc.

    return rootView;
}
```

So maybe you'd best pass the root `View` as parameter into `setUpRecyclerView()` and use it as follows:

```
private void setUpRecyclerView(ViewGroup root){
    Query query = eventRef.limit(8);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Event> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Event>()
            .setQuery(query, Event.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new EventRecyclerAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.events_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(root.getContext()));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```